# Index all the rights

Tags: sharepoint-online, api

I have been trying to see the rights on folders within a sharepoint list. I haven't been able to do so with Powershell.

Is there a way to do it with Python? I need all the rights on all folders. So we need to know which person has which rights on which folder.

I hope the question is clear

Comment: have you tried my script?

Answer (score 0):

**Use PNP module and cmds:**

1. Use `Get-PNPfolder` [documentation here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpfolder?view=sharepoint-ps), `Get-PNPlist` [documentation here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplist?view=sharepoint-ps), with `-Includes RoleAssignments`
2. [example here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Developer/Get-Site-Permissions-with-PnP-PowerShell/td-p/140002)

**Here is script:**

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://kpcs.sharepoint.com/sites/zvi
$context = Get-PnPContext
$folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url "/sites/zvi/Shared Documents/test" -Includes ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments, ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments
$context.Load($folder);
$context.ExecuteQuery();

if($folder.ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True) 
{
    foreach($roleAssignments in $folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments)
    {
        Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $roleAssignments -Property RoleDefinitionBindings, Member

        Write-Host $roleAssignments.Member.LoginName","$roleAssignments.Member.Title","$roleAssignments.Member.PrincipalType.ToString()","$roleAssignments.RoleDefinitionBindings[0].Name
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: We have tried the get-pnpfolder command but we did not succeed. Do we need to combine get-pnplist with get-pnpfolder?

Comment: Get-PnPProperty : Cannot bind parameter 'ClientObject'. Cannot convert the "$folderitems" value of type
"System.String" to type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject".
At line:1 char:16
+ $folderitems | Get-PnPProperty
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-PnPProperty], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.EnsureProperty    This is the error i am getting

Comment: try this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/resolve-pnpfolder?view=sharepoint-ps look at examples

Comment: It points to Get-PnPFolder what we have tried and didn't get us anything. And I can't get get-childitem of resolve-pnpfolder. I don't know what parameters i need to get rights of the folders.

Comment: i will do this script tomorrow.

Comment: script added, dont forget to vote and mark his answer :)